# Travelling to Germany with Permeso di Soggiorno (Residence Permit) receipt

Tags: schengen, flixbus

I am supposed to submit my original documents for university enrollment in Germany in the 1st week of October. I am currently waiting for my renewed Italian stay permit. The Old permit has expired but I have the receipt of the new one that I'm waiting for. Can I travel to Germany and be back in 3 days time for my permit?

Comment: Also related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/33891/19400